Solutions to a Congruence Involving a Tuple Counting Function.
Let $A(b, k, i)$ be the number of integer tuples $(x_1, \dots, x_{k+1})$
such that $0 \le x_j \le b-1$ and $|x_j - x_{j+1}| = i$ for all $j$, for $ b \geq 1$.
Let $S_k(b) = \sum_{i=0}^{b-1} A(b,k,i)$ and  $V_k(b) = S_k(b+2) - 2S_k(b+1) + S_k(b)$ .
Here, it is proved that $V_k(b)$ is periodic with minimal period equal to $LCM(1,2,\cdots,k)$.
Let's consider $V_k(b) \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$, i have found that for $k=2,3,4,5,7,11,23$ the only solutions are $V_k(km-1)$ for $m \geq 1$. Is there any connection between such k and primes? Can we prove whether the number of such $k$ is finite/infinite?
For $k=6$ the only solutions are $V_k(12m+c)$, for $m\geq0$, where $c \in \{2,3,7,8,11\} $ and for $k=8$ the only solutions are $V_k(24m+c)$, for $m\geq0$, where $c \in \{3,5,17,19,23\}. $
It looks like that for any $k \geq 2 $ the solutions are $V_k(pm+c)$, for $m\geq0$, where $c \in A$ and $A$ is some non-empty set, and $k \mid p$.
